# Comma delimited text input parameter (multiple values) in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx, ssrs-2012

I would like to enter in (type) multiple values as parameters, separated by a comma. For example:

[image]

I have altered the ProductArticle Dataset to the following:

```
="WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Product].
[Article].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
[Product].[Article].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] 
AS [Product].[Article].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL SELECT {[Measures].
[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} 
ON COLUMNS, [Product].[Article].[Article].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM [Operational] 
where ([Product].[Article Key].&[" & Left(Parameters!ArticleInput.Value,5) 
& "], [Product].[Active].&[Active])"
```

And I am using the following parameters:

[ArticleInput (*available and default values not specified*) 
ProductArticle (*available and default values connected to the ProductArticle dataset*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM4Sf.png)

[image]

This works good for one parameter entry, but I need to know how I can make this work with multiple values.

Comment: Have you tried using an IN clause in your query, ie `WHERE [Product].[ArticleID] IN (@ArticleInput)`

Comment: When I run the report I recieve the following error message: "The value provided for the report parameter 'Article Input' is not valid for its type"

Comment: See edit above - Are you confident the value being passed to the query is in the format 111,222,333?

Comment: I have tried using the IN clause, but without success. Yes, the value will be the 6 digit article number. If the user wants too see multiple articles then the number will be separated by a comma. The user should be able to enter unlimited article numbers.

Comment: @krynil The `IN` operator cannot be used in a MDX `where` clause. You have to convert your strings to well formed members. If it is not clear for you let me know I'll post an answer.

Comment: @krynil you need to split, via commas, and then rebuilt with the relevent `[dim].[hier].[<>]` wrapped around each key value

Comment: You can't pass a comma delimited list if the datatype of the parameter is set to integer.  That is likely the cause of the error message you mentioned.

Comment: @krynil did my answer help you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

set Allow multiple values property value to true of report parameter property 
and use following code as a expression inside the textbox

=join(Parameters!parameterName.Value,",")

Comment: He wants to be able to type the values into a textbox for a parameter, not select them from a list, not display the joined list on the report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I already have a textbox with =Join(Parameters!ProductArticle.Label, ","). I'm having an issue with typing in multiple parameters and viewing the report.